# Woocommerce. В каком файле отображение товаров?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Здравствуйте. Подскажите пожалуйста в каком файле HTML код отображения таблицы товаров? Т.е. заходим в категорию, видим сетку товаров, там изображение, цена, а как настроить отображение вывода этой всей категории? Допустим хочу добавить к каждому товару еще что-нибудь.

Answer (score 2):

Для отображения группы товаров используется шаблон `archive-product.php`. Он находится в папке темы: `themes/theme-name/archive-product.php` или `themes/theme-name/woocommerce/archive-product.php`. Если в используемой теме нет такого шаблона, то используется шаблон по умолчанию, который находится в папке плагина: `plugins/woocommerce/templates/archive-product.php`.

За вывод каждого отдельного товара отвечает шаблон `content-product.php`. Чтобы его вызвать, в файле `archive-product.php` используется функция `wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );`. Файл шаблона `content-product.php` также ищется сперва в папке темы, а если не был найден, то используется шаблон по умолчанию, находящийся в папке плагина.

Если будете вносить изменения, то делать это нужно для файла, который находится в папке с темой. Если файла `content-product.php` нет в папке темы, то скопируйте туда шаблон по умолчанию и корректируйте его.