# Отобразить изображения галереи продуктов поверх представленного изображения WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Подскажите пожалуйста, необходимо отобразить изображения галереи продуктов поверх представленного изображения на странице магазина WooCommerce. Скриншот прилагаю:

[image: Скриншот с необходимым результатом]

Нужно написать специальний код PHP для этого. Где и в каком файле его разместить, чтобы не повредить WordPress и последующие обновления.

Ничего вразумительного не нагуглил.
Вот нашел [похожий ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/542526/woocommerce).
Пробовал, но встает коряво или выдает ошибку.

Comment: Написать плагин. https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0

Comment: Если это сложно, то какие могут быть разговоры про "написать код"? Используй готовые решения - плагины (или что там где как тебе надо не понятно).

Comment: "Добрый" Вы.. проблема в том что такого плагина не существует и прогуглив 2е суток ничего не нашел

Comment: Уважаемый, 1) если ты не нашел - не значит что такого нет. 2) [проблема XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/504949). Если бы ты спрашивал "как вывести", при этом подробно описав что где и как, то можно было бы что-то посоветовать. Но ты же спрашиваешь совсем другое.

Comment: Хорошо.. в архиве товаров над изображениями товаров надо вывести по одному дополнительному фото товаров. так понятней? я тут впервой, не судите строго

Comment: пробовал через плагин ACF добавить кастомное поле и вывести его в archive-product.php с помощью команды <?php the_field('photo_prod') ?>. Ругнулось ошибкой Parse error: syntax error, unexpected identifier "woocommerce_product_loop_end" in D:\OpenServer\domains\test\wp-content\themes\twentytwenty\archive-product.php on line 75

Comment: Тут не форум, а ФАК-сервис.  Новая задача - новый вопрос (задавай отдельно)